# Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe. Apache is unable to raad .htaccess files

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, server

```
Forbidden
```

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at www.itexpertsbd.com Port 80

**I could not find any way how to solve this**

Comment: Does the user account running Apache have access to the configured DocumentRoot? (check directory permissions)

Comment: Yes it has the access on the document root

Comment: How have you confirmed that? Can you try running `ls /path/to/document/root` as the same user that is running Apache?

Comment: yes. i added new htaccess file but the server is telling that its unable to read .htaccess